# maximum of numbers being strange

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
numbers=[]
maximum=0
while True:
    number =input("Enter a number:")
    if number == "0":
        break
    else:
        numbers.append(number)
print ("The largest number entered was:")
print (max(numbers))
```

This seems to work for numbers below 10 only when I enter these numbers:

```
Enter a number:10
Enter a number:9
Enter a number:3
Enter a number:4
Enter a number:23
Enter a number:0
The largest number entered was:
9
```

As you can see, the largest number is actually 23, but it printed 9, what have I done wrong?

Comment: `9` is the highest string entered, lexicographically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending strings, append integers instead:

`numbers.append(int(number))`

Or better:

```
while True:
    number = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    if not number:
        break
    else:
        numbers.append(number)
```

EDIT: you can wrap the integer conversion with `try-except` block to make sure user enters only digits:

```
while True:
    nb = input('Enter a number:')
    try:
        nb = int(nb)
        if not nb:
            break
        else:
            numbers.append(nb)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please Enter Valid Number')
print ("The largest number entered was:")
print (max(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks for this it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the lexicographical maximum, which is 9. This is due to your building the `numbers` container from string types.

To return the numeric maximum, build your container with integers using `append(int(number))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could append it as `int` or print `max` with `map` and `int` to your `list`:

```
print (max(map(int, numbers)))
```